# in Beeline,use "create table table_name as select * from" doesn't work

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

in Beeline,i use "`create table new_table_name as select * from exists_name`" to create a new table,the table was created successfully, but there is no data.When i use the same "`select * from exists_name`" to create a temporary table,the temporary table has data.
the Beeline version is `Beeline version 3.1.0.3.1.5.0-152 by Apache Hive`

Comment: What was your exact create SQL? Because beeline/command tool sometime doesnt create into correct schema. did you use it like `create table target_db.new_table_name as select * from source_db.exists_name`

Comment: yes,i try use ```create table target_db.new_table_name as select * from source_db.exists_name```.It didn't work too

Comment: did you get job summary message like this - `INFO  : Execution completed successfully
INFO  : Moving data to: hdfs://loc/tmp from hdfs://db-ns/    sw/schema/.hive-staging_hive_2020-08-03_00-58-40_904_7739683806805718609-35074
INFO  : Starting task [Stage-2:STATS] in serial mode
INFO  : Table schema.tmp stats: [numFiles=2, numRows=2414, total    Size=450056, rawDataSize=447642]
INFO  : Completed executing command(queryId=hive_20200803005858_123d8faf-df00-4e4b-9ba5-2b91858a7b54); Time taken: 102.659 seconds
INFO  : OK
No rows affected (103.867 seconds)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I checked the HIVE official documents about `Create Table As Select (CTAS)`,
CTAS has these restrictions:

1. The target table cannot be an external table.
2. The target table cannot be a list bucketing table.

in Beeline,when i use `create table new_table_name as select * from exists_name` to create a new table,it's always create an external table,maybe this reason